# Get column of last character in visual line - Vimscript

Tags: vimscript, functions

In one of my vim scripts I require the column of the last non-whitespace character of the current line and the column of the last character of the current line (when the current line is wrapped into two or more lines) I would like to get the column of the last character on the same visual line.

How could I acquire these columns?

**Example:**

```
thisis[o]nelonglineXXXXX
thisisstillthesameline
```

*Cursor marked as*: [ ]
*Whitespace marked as*: X

Expected result:

- Column of last **e** in first line
- Column of last **X** in first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I cooked up. It uses `g$` to find the end of the visual line.

```
function! GetLastVisualColumn(nonBlankFlag)
   " Save the original spot
   let originalPos = getpos('.')

   " Put cursor at last character on visual line
   normal! g$

   " If caller specified nonBank and the cursor is on whitespace then jump to the
   "   most recent end of word
   if (a:nonBlankFlag)
      if matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') =~ '\s'
         " This black magic just finds out if the character under the cursor is whitespace.
         normal! ge
      endif
   endif

   " Save column
   let column = getpos('.')[2]

   " Go back to original position
   call setpos('.', originalPos)

   return column
endfunction
```

It moves the cursor around (and then puts it back), but as longs as that's not an issue it should work for you. Pass it `0` for end of visual line, or `1` for last non-blank character on the visual line.

For more info see: `:h normal`, `:h g$`, `:h matchstr`, `:h getpos()`, and `:h setpos()`.

Comment: You could also use `getpos()` and `setpos()` instead of `m'` and `\`\`` so the mark is not changed without the user knowing why.

Comment: Good point. I'll update it.